# How can I implement Scalable Broadcast algorithm in aodv?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to implement Scalable Broadcast algorithm for flooding in aodv. However, I can not understand how I can restrict the transmission to specific nodes only. Is there any predefined function available in inet for this?
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you could Google a bit and then post here what you have tried, it will help us help you.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by 'scalable broadcast'. AODV is an algorithm for establishing unicast routes, not for multi/geo/broadcast. For more information about AODV, have a look a [the INET tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/step10.html). Are you talking about some algorithm that optimizes how the route request broadcasts work? In that case, you should change how RREQs are dealt with.